# How to construct network or graph?

Tags: r, networking

I have two files one is list of interactions with ensembl ids and other is disease name with ensembl id.One gene may be involved in more than one diseases. I have create to create a network like below figure.

[image]

Please find the sample input,

```
first_column = c("ENSG00000142192", "ENSG00000140575", "ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000165588", "ENSG00000213551", "ENSG00000213551","ENSG00000197153")
second_column = c("ENSG00000074800", " ENSG00000115966", "ENSG00000186908", "ENSG00000135446", "ENSG00000273983", "ENSG00000274267","ENSG00000213551")
df2 = data.frame(first_column,second_column)
first_column = c("ENSG00000213551","ENSG00000165588","ENSG00000213551")
second_column = c("Malignant neoplasm of breast","Malignant neoplasm of breast","Schizophrenia")
df1 = data.frame(first_column,second_column)
```

Comment: "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: Which network analysis/network graphing packages or functions have you tried?